# Cygwin configure: error: source directory already configured; run "make distclean" there first

Tags: unix, cygwin

Hi I am using cygwin to build FFTW library.

But, when I type 'configure' the error pops out as- configure: error: source directory already configured; run "make distclean" there first

But,When I again type 'make distclean' another error pops out: make: *** No rule to make target 'distclean'.  Stop.

Pleas provide suggestions on this.

Comment: Tell me the FFWT library version, please ? Did you use the source distributed by tar.gz ?

Comment: I am using fftw 2.1.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't determine your environment, so I only to guess.
At first, you should execute `bootstrap.sh`, then execute `configure` and other `make` commands.

**EDIT:**
Direct reason is below code in `configure`.
You should try delete `config.status` and execute `bootstrap.sh` && `./configure`.

```
1715  # test to see if srcdir already configured
1716 if test "`cd $srcdir && pwd`" != "`pwd`" &&
1717    test -f $srcdir/config.status; then
1718   { { echo "$as_me:$LINENO: error: source directory already configured; run \"make distclean\" there first" >&5
1719 echo "$as_me: error: source directory already configured; run \"make distclean\" there first" >&2;}
1720    { (exit 1); exit 1; }; }
1721 fi
```

Comment: It worked after running bootstrap.sh first. Thanks @panzer_jagdiron